# How to configure Wifi on Hololens emulator instead of Ethernet?

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, hololens-emulator

I want to deploy an IoT app on Hololens Emulator.
This Unity app is made using Unity and Azure IoT Hub SDK. The big picture is to create a telemetry application using Raspberry Pi, Unity and Azure Cloud. I want to receive sensors data on my Unity app through Azure Cloud, and specially Azure IoT Hub the dedicated service for IoT system.

Sensors + raspberry pi => Azure Cloud => Unity app.

According to the Azure SDK, the IoT app needs a WiFi connection.

But the Hololens emulator is running using Ethernet connection. To deploy the build project on the emulator, it seems that the Ethernet connection is required. When I used WiFi, and error appears during the deployment.

After some tests, I conclude that my app can access to internet on the emulator, but the way using Ethernet or Wifi is the issue.

Test 0: Deploy the Unity app on Unity editor using Ethernet connection
Internet on the app: Yes
Connection to Azure Cloud: No

Test 1: Deploy the Unity app on Unity editor using Wifi connection
Internet on the app: Yes
Connection to Azure Cloud: Yes

Test 2: Deploy the Unity app on Hololens emulator using Visual Studio and Ethernet connection.
Deployment: success
Internet on Hololens: Yes
Internet on the app: Yes
Connection to Azure Cloud: No

Test 3: Deploy the Unity app on Hololens emulator using Visual Studio and Wifi connection.
Deployment: failed

Does the emulator support wifi connection?
Once the app is deployed on the emulator, it is possible to configure wifi?

Unity 2019

- Platform: UWP Scripting Runtime: NET 4.x
- Scripting Backend: IL2CPP
- API Compatibility level: NET 4.x
- Publishing config:InternetClientServer, PrivateNetworkClientServer

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

The HoloLens Emulator is built on Hyper-V.  Virtual machines in Hyper-V will always have an Ethernet adapter, not a WiFi adapter, so while you can share the WiFi connection from your host PC to the virtual machine, it will appear in the virtual machine as Ethernet.

In order to potentially enable your scenario, I would focus on removing the WiFi requirement from the app if possible.  Can you please provide a link to the documentation where you're seeing that a WiFi connection is required?